# Creating a List from another List, filtered by certain indexes

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<decimal>` and I want to create a new `List<decimal>` from a subset of the first List.

Code example:

```
List<decimal> set1 = new List<decimal>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
```

How do I create a new List that is from index=2 to index=4 (30, 40, 50)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var set2 = set1.Skip(2).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: `+1` for fastest gun in the west.

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = set1.Select((r, i) => new { Index = i, Value = r })
               .Where(t => t.Index >= 2 && t.Index <= 4)
               .Select(r => r.Value);
```

If you want to have a List you can append `ToList` to the query.

For output

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

output:

```
30
40
50
```

Comment: Why in god's name is this downvoted? It's a perfectly viable answer like the rest of them.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx)

```
var newlist = set1.GetRange(2,3);
```

You are passing starting index (2) and number of items you will get (3)